# How to return multiple views in one function in laravel for same route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-routing

it is quite difficult to explain my question. I hope you will be able understand it.

For my project I have a master layout which contains the header and yield of content.

*master.blade.php*

```
 @include('partials.header')
    <div class="container-fluid main-con">
        @yield('content')
        @include('partials.footer')
    </div>
```

now on main public route I am raturning a method.

*Web.php*

```
Route::get('/', [
    'uses' => 'ProductContoller@getIndex',
    'as' => 'product.mainCats'
]);
```

*ProductContoller.php*

```
class ProductContoller extends Controller
{

    public function getIndex(){
        $ad_cats = Mainaddtype::orderBy('title')->get();
        return view( 'shop.main-categories-page', ['mediacats' => $ad_cats]);
    }
}
```

---

Now my query is, 'main-categories-page' is yielding in content section of master. but I want the same data of Mainadtype in header also. So I want to return view of header on same function. Please help if u understand it.

what I am trying now is,

```
 public function getIndex(){
        $ad_cats = Mainaddtype::orderBy('title')->get();
        return view( 'shop.main-categories-page', ['mediacats' => $ad_cats]);
        return view( 'partials.header', ['mediacats' => $ad_cats]);
    }
```

But I know we cant return in this way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the variable in the header as well. Just have a check to see if the variable exists so that you don't get errors when you load other views.

```
@if(!empty($mediacats))
   // do awesome stuffs with $mediacats
@endif
```

This way your data will be available when you are on index page.

If you want the data to be available in all views, you can use [laravel view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers). From official docs:

> View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a
>   view is rendered. If you have data that you want to be bound to a view
>   each time that view is rendered, a view composer can help you organize
>   that logic into a single location

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanxx alot sir! that works!!!!! I was trying so hard to get this. Thank u so much :)

Comment: glad that I could help.

Answer (score 1):

function gets terminate as it gets the first return statement and also two views can't be returned in laravel, the only possible thing you can do is include view in layout template. example adding category view in template.

```
@if(showStore)
@include('store.category')
@endif
```